# Array of objects as dataSource for Material Angular table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

My `user` data looks like this which is causing issues...

```
[{"firstName":"Pinkie","lastName":"Connelly","username":"Darlene.Marvin","email":"Isobel_Renner@hotmail.com"},{"firstName":"Easter","lastName":"Ruecker","username":"Giovani.Collier59","email":"Annamae54@gmail.com"},{"firstName":"Harmon","lastName":"Luettgen","username":"Rosanna51","email":"Moshe98@yahoo.com"},{"firstName":"Angeline","lastName":"Kunze","username":"Gabriel_Braun69","email":"Jackson21@hotmail.com"},{"firstName":"Gayle","lastName":"Bahringer","username":"Dorcas_Roob55","email":"Greyson96@gmail.com"},{"firstName":"Adriana","lastName":"Renner","username":"Serenity.Armstrong42","email":"Sim.Robel@gmail.com"},{"firstName":"Arvid","lastName":"Kiehn","username":"Estrella87","email":"Jaylan_Morissette70@yahoo.com"},{"firstName":"Kristofer","lastName":"Nader","username":"Terence.Walker7","email":"Brady99@hotmail.com"},{"firstName":"Rosa","lastName":"Lebsack","username":"Freida_Hegmann46","email":"Alanna_Schmitt89@hotmail.com"},{"firstName":"Rogers","lastName":"Thiel","username":"Mike_Braun","email":"Agnes.Shields3@gmail.com"}]
```

I am using Angular and imported Material Angular. The first problem I had was using `*NgFor` with this data structure, but since Angular V6 you can now use a `keyValue` pipe which is really cool! so that problem solved.

I then wanted to *NgFor into a table so each person would populate a row. You dont use NgFor for a table, instead it uses dataSource -

```
<table mat-table #table [dataSource]="user">
  <!-- table rows -->
</table>
```

But again... `Provided data source did not match an array, Observable, or DataSource at getTableUnknownDataSourceError`

This is how I am getting `user` -

```
export class AppComponent {
  error: any;
  title = 'toms-app';
  user: User;

constructor(private apiServicefile: ApiServicefile) { }


ngOnInit(): void {
  this.apiServicefile.getUser()
    .subscribe(
      (data: User) => this.user = { ...data }, // success path
      error => this.error = error // error path
    );
}
}
```

New to typeScript and how to go about getting my desired result. please help?

Comment: Replace `this.user = { ...data }` by `this.users = data`. You get an array from the server, and you need this array for your datasource. Why transform it to an object? Rename `user` to `users`, since it's an **array** of users and not a single User. And thus change its type to Array<User>.

Answer (score 1):

this.user is not an Array after:

```
{ ...data };
```

Just do it like this:

```
this.user = data;
```

Or by the way you can improve it a bit like this, html:

```
<table mat-table #table [dataSource]="user | async">
  <!-- table rows -->
</table>
```

In TS file you user is:

```
Array<User>
```

, not an User, but as we write in html user with 'async' pipe you can define it like:

```
Observable<Array<User>> or Observable<User[]>
```

and assign this.apiServicefile.getUser() to this field.

```
export class AppComponent {
  error: any;
  title = 'toms-app';
  user: Observable<Array<User>>;

  constructor(private apiServicefile: ApiServicefile) { }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.user = this.apiServicefile.getUser();
  }
}
```